# XSD : how to describe most simple element for castor

Tags: java, xsd, castor

Trying to work with castor oxm using xsd.
How to describe in XSD very simple element witch does not contain anything: no text, no attributes, no nested elements, just own element :

```
<ComplexElement>
   <VerySimpleElement/>
   <Element>42</Element>
</ComplexElement>
```

?

If I use :

```
<xs:element name="ComplexElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="VerySimpleElement"/>
                <!-- there will be more -->
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="DoesNotMatter"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Castor Code Gen gives me VerySimpleElement as ... an Object!!! :

```
/**
 * Field _verySimpleElement.
 */
private java.lang.Object _verySimpleElement;
```

And **the only** way to fill it correct - put there as Object ... :

```
new AnyNode(AnyNode.ELEMENT, "VerySimpleElement", null, null, null);
```

It looks like so ugly...

Have somebody any ideas?